# RSpec has_many through #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, associations

I have a has many through relationship model like this:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I need to create a Physician which has many Patients, right?
so on my test:

```
let!(:physician) { create(:physician) }
let!(:patients) { create_list(:patients, 2) }
```

and I did this:

```
before { physician.patients << patients }
```

I want to test the generated json with this

```
expect(physician.as_json).to eq({
  "id" => physician.id,
  "name" => physician.name,
  "patients" => physician.patients
})
```

I am expecting it would pass but it failed because of this `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy>`

I checked using `binding.pry` by this:

`physician.patients == patients`
and the result was `true`

**Would you mind helping me, am I missing something here?**

Comment: `physician.patients` is a collection of records. It is not equal to the expected **json data**. There are multiple ways of writing this, but basically your test is wrong -- you need to somehow define the **json format** that the expected result should be.

Comment: `#as_json` despite the name returns a serializable hash - not JSON. Otherwise your comment is spot on @TomLord

Comment: thank you @TomLord I was able to solve my case with all your comments.

Comment: as well as @max for expounding and clarifying what Tom Lord commented. I believe the solution I came up with came from your comments

Answer (score 1):

To link physician and patients just pass the key to `create_list`:

```
let!(:patients) { create_list(:patients, 2, physician: physician ) }
```

Or you can declare it as:

```
let(:physician) { create(:physician, patients: build_list(patients: 2)) }
```

But the test itself is still broken as mentioned by @TomLord. You need test the resulting hash - as including an association will cause it be converted to a  serialized hash:

```
{
  "id" => 1,
  "name" => "Dr Suess",
  "patients" => [
     {
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "The Cat in The Hat"
     },
     {
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "The Grinch"
     },
  ]
}
```

Testing the exact output with `eq` is not optimal as each change to the serialization will break the test. Instead you can use the [`include` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) to specify what must be present:

```
describe '#as_json' do
   let!(:physician) { create(:physician) }
   let!(:patients) { create_list(:patients, 2) }
   subject(:serialized) { physician.as_json } 

   it { should include({
        "id" => physician.id,
        "name" => physician.name
   }) }
   it "includes the patients" do
      expect(serialized["patients"].length).to eq patients.length
      expect(serialized["patients"]).to include patients.first.as_json
      expect(serialized["patients"]).to include patients.last.as_json
   end
end
```

Unless you have overridden the `as_json` method this spec should fail as you need to explicitly include associations with `physician.as_json(include: :patients)`.

Comment: Overriding as_json is not a very good solution in the first place - you might want to rethink the general approach. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json